# ATI Driver not working after system update?

Tags: 10.04, drivers, ati, jockey

I had a working Ubuntu 10.04 desktop with ATI drivers with three monitors on a Radion HD 5750.

After a standard `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade; reboot`

I got a black screen (system booted, but graphics did not display at login screen). I went into recovery mode and reset to basic graphics mode.

Currently, the Catalyst control center says the ATI driver is not installed. But the "hardware drivers" tool (jockey) says "ATI Fire GL" is installed and in use.

So either:
1. The driver is not actually installed even though jockey claims it is, or
2. The driver is installed but catalyst can't find/use it.

I used apt-get to purge and then reinstall the ATI drivers with no improvement.

How do I get this driver working again? Is there a way to completely purge/remove everything graphics related and start over like a clean system, but without an OS reinstall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jockey re-downloads everything on every driver re-install as far as I know.

Use jockey to remove the driver, reboot, re-install the driver also through jockey, and you should be fixed.

This is a common problem for people that compile the latest ATI driver themselves.  If you did that, you need to remove all the self-compiled components so that jockey and the jockey installed `amdcccle` appear first in your search path and just work.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling through Jockey too, but that had no effect. I don't believe that I compiled the driver myself... but how can I check to see if I have "self-compiled components" installed just to be sure?

Comment: if you remove it through jockey and running amdcccle produces a dialog, you have self compiled components

Comment: I removed the driver with jockey and still get an error when running `amdcccle`. So I guess I do have self compiled components somewhere. How do I find and get rid of them?

Comment: `which amdcccle` should tell you where it is.  an `ls -la` in that directory should tell you where the link goes.  I can't see that directory listing so saying delete everything there is a not okay thing to do, but you need to delete everything related to the self-compiled driver.

Comment: `which amdcccle` shows `/usr/bin/amdcccle` which is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/amdcccle` which is a symlink to `/usr/lib/fglrx/bin/amdcccle`. `/usr/lib/fglrx/bin/amdcccle` appears to be the actual executable file. Do I want to remove `/usr/lib/fglrx`?

Comment: yes.  that's the one.  make sure you're using the open driver first though

Comment: So I should use: `rm /usr/lib/fglrx -r` and then delete all of the symlinks?

Comment: just mv it first, then follow the directions here: how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_find_broken_symbolic_links to get rid of the broken links

Comment: OK, I've moved the files and removed the symlinks. Turning the driver on and off in jockey didn't seem to do anything (it didn't redownload or install and there was no change after reboot except whether it thought the driver was in use or not). I purged the fglrx packages and rebooted, and now jockey has no suggestions. Still not sure what to try.

Comment: if you reinstalled through jockey and it's showing in use, try `apt-get install --reinstall -f fglrx-amdcccle`...after that, I'm all out of suggestions

Comment: Well, couldn't get it working. I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu. It also turns out that my three monitor set-up does require the ATI driver, the one through Jockey does not support 3 screens correctly. Thanks for all you help!